# How do I link 2 or more tables together in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Sup SO.

I'm learning MVC 5 and ASP.NET among other technologies for databases and web and I am doing a sample project within that context. So far I have managed to create a website that displays three tables successfully, and you can search through at least one of them, and create new entries, edit and delete existing entries for all three of them.

What I need to do now is link those three together, much like I would with INNER JOIN in SQL.

So the tables are Employees, Skill Proficiencies and Skill Descriptions.

- The Employees all have a set of skills they know and a level of proficiency attached to each one. They also have an Employee ID.
- The Skill Proficiencies table holds the data of which employee knows what skill and at what level, but only holds Employee IDs and Skill IDs to match them, in addition to an int signifying the level of proficiency.
- The Skill Description table holds the Skill ID for each skill, and a human readable name for it, like C++, HTML and so on.

**In this instance the desired effect would be a single table with each entry having a name of an employee (taken from the Employees table), the name of a skill (taken from the Skill Descriptions table) and a proficiency level for that employee and skill (taken from the Skill Proficiencies table).**

What I have found on the subject so far has either been for another version of MVC, or has shown how to do so in a way that returns the data as plain text, whereas I want it returned in a list, much like I already am doing as displayed below.

EmployeesController:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SDS.Models;
using System;

namespace SDS.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeesController : Controller
    {
        private SDSDbContext db = new SDSDbContext();

        // GET: Employees
        public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
        {
            var employeesQuery = from e in db.Employees select e;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                employeesQuery = employeesQuery.Where(x => x.FirstName.Contains(searchString)
                                                    || x.MiddleName.Contains(searchString)
                                                    || x.LastName.Contains(searchString)
                                                    || x.EmployeeAID.ToString().Contains(searchString)
                                                    || x.StaffNo.ToString().Contains(searchString)
                                                    || x.JobTitle.Contains(searchString));
            }

            return View(employeesQuery.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Employees/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Employee employee = db.Employees.Find(id);
            if (employee == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(employee);
        }

        // GET: Employees/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Employees/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "EmployeeID,EmployeeAID,FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,StaffNo,JobTitle")] Employee employee)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Employees.Add(employee);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(employee);
        }

        // GET: Employees/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Employee employee = db.Employees.Find(id);
            if (employee == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(employee);
        }

        // POST: Employees/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "EmployeeID,EmployeeAID,FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,StaffNo,JobTitle")] Employee employee)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            } 
           return View(employee);
        }

        // GET: Employees/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Employee employee = db.Employees.Find(id);
            if (employee == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(employee);
        }

        // POST: Employees/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Employee employee = db.Employees.Find(id);
            db.Employees.Remove(employee);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
               db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Employee Model:

```
namespace SDS.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

        public int EmployeeAID { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string MiddleName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public int StaffNo { get; set; }

        public string JobTitle { get; set; }

        public SkillDescription skillDescription { get; set; }

        public SkillProficiency skillProficiency { get; set; }
    }
}
```

SkillDescriptions Controller:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SDS.Models;

namespace SDS.Controllers
{
    public class SkillDescriptionsController : Controller
    {
        private SDSDbContext db = new SDSDbContext();

        // GET: SkillDescriptions
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.SkillDescriptions.ToList());
        }

        // GET: SkillDescriptions/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            SkillDescription skillDescription = db.SkillDescriptions.Find(id);
            if (skillDescription == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(skillDescription);
        }

        // GET: SkillDescriptions/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: SkillDescriptions/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Description")] SkillDescription skillDescription)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.SkillDescriptions.Add(skillDescription);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(skillDescription);
        }

        // GET: SkillDescriptions/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            SkillDescription skillDescription = db.SkillDescriptions.Find(id);
            if (skillDescription == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(skillDescription);
        }

        // POST: SkillDescriptions/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,Description")] SkillDescription skillDescription)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(skillDescription).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(skillDescription);
        }

        // GET: SkillDescriptions/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            SkillDescription skillDescription = db.SkillDescriptions.Find(id);
            if (skillDescription == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(skillDescription);
        }

        // POST: SkillDescriptions/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            SkillDescription skillDescription = db.SkillDescriptions.Find(id);
            db.SkillDescriptions.Remove(skillDescription);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

SkillDescription Model:

```
namespace SDS.Models
{
    public class SkillDescription
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

SkillProficiencies Controller:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SDS.Models;

namespace SDS.Controllers
{
    public class SkillProficienciesController : Controller
    {
        private SDSDbContext db = new SDSDbContext();

        // GET: SkillProficiencies
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.SkillProficiencies.ToList());
        }

        // GET: SkillProficiencies/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            SkillProficiency skillProficiency = db.SkillProficiencies.Find(id);
            if (skillProficiency == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(skillProficiency);
        }

        // GET: SkillProficiencies/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: SkillProficiencies/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,EmployeeAID,SkillID,Proficiency1To5")] SkillProficiency skillProficiency)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.SkillProficiencies.Add(skillProficiency);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(skillProficiency);
        }

        // GET: SkillProficiencies/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            SkillProficiency skillProficiency = db.SkillProficiencies.Find(id);
            if (skillProficiency == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(skillProficiency);
        }

        // POST: SkillProficiencies/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,EmployeeAID,SkillID,Proficiency1To5")] SkillProficiency skillProficiency)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(skillProficiency).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(skillProficiency);
        }

        // GET: SkillProficiencies/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            SkillProficiency skillProficiency = db.SkillProficiencies.Find(id);
            if (skillProficiency == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(skillProficiency);
        }

        // POST: SkillProficiencies/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            SkillProficiency skillProficiency = db.SkillProficiencies.Find(id);
            db.SkillProficiencies.Remove(skillProficiency);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

SkillProficiency Model:

```
namespace SDS.Models
{
    public class SkillProficiency
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public int EmployeeAID { get; set; }

        public int SkillID { get; set; }

        public int Proficiency1To5 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And just to give you an idea of how the data is being displayed right now, here's the Index.cshtml of the SkillsProficiency table:

```
@model IEnumerable<SDS.Models.SkillProficiency>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Skill Proficiencies";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmployeeAID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SkillID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Proficiency1To5)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeAID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SkillID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Proficiency1To5)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Ideally, I would like to keep the current list look of the page when I link the tables. Here's what the Skills Proficiency table looks like now:

[image: Skills Proficiencies Table]

Answer (score 1):

Your question is information overload. Normally, user's don't post enough, but you've swung the opposite way and posted far more than is necessary. This comes down to simply your entity classes. I'd encourage you to spend some time getting up to speed with Entity Framework, since this is pretty much 101 stuff.

That said, Entity Framework needs to know that those foreign key properties actually apply to some entity class. It's not omniscient. Also, you've got some logic errors in your database structure. What you essentially have here is an M2M with a payload. Employees have many skills and and skill have many employees, but the relationship between the two requires the additional payload of a proficiency score.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeSkill> Skills { get; set; }
}

public class Skill
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeSkill> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeSkill
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Employee")]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Skill")]
    public int SkillId { get; set; }
    public virtual Skill Skill { get; set; }

    public int Proficiency1To5 { get; set; }
}
```

Here `EmployeeSkill` represents your join table for the M2M relationship. Traditionally, you'd reference the related entity directly and let Entity Framework handle the join table implicitly, but since there's a payload involved (proficiency), you need to manually construct that relationship. With that in place, you can then do something like:

```
var employee = db.Employees.Include("Skills.Skill").SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
```

Then, you can get all the information you need:

```
foreach (var skill in employee.Skills)
{
    // Skill Description = skill.Skill.Description
    // Skill Proficiency = skill.Proficiency1to5    
}
```

Comment: Where should I add that last employee declaration and foreach loop? The SkillProficiencies Controller?

Comment: Wherever you want. It's mostly just to show the use of `Include` to fetch the related entities at the same time and give you a general idea of how to get at the properties you need from the skills. That said, the employee declaration should go in your controller or in some method on a service or repository that you utilize in your controller, simply because it's bad form to hit the database in your view. Where and how you utilize the actual data, however, is entirely up to you and the needs of your application.